# Closest method in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The closest() is used for below,

For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and **traversing up** through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

instead of traversing up , i need to traverse down, is it possible

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/ ?

Comment: [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an equivilent to .closest() that searchs down the DOM tree instead of up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139375/is-there-an-equivilent-to-closest-that-searchs-down-the-dom-tree-instead-of-u)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use the `.find()` method and use either `[0]` or `.first()`

E.g.:

`$('parent').find('searchSelector').first();`

Answer (score 0):

try `.find()`. Depends on how your page is structured etc

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of `closest()` is `parents('.selector').last()`.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/9H6tT/)

Comment: No, it's not: the opposite of `prevAll()` is `nextAll()` (think lateral movement); the opposite of `closest()` is `find()` (in terms of vertical movement (ancestors/descendants) through the DOM, though finding many instead of `closest()`'s one). And, again, `parents()` goes in the same direction as `closest()`: the OP *specifically* says he wants to "traverse down."

Comment: @DavidThomas yeah, sorry got the wrong method. I meant `parents(sel).last()`