# how to change hidden value with jQuery after clicking div

Tags: jquery

I am appending some images in a function but when I click on any of the appended images I want to change the hidden value to "Yes". It is by default set to "No".

```
var id = $(this).data("id");
$( ".thumbs" ).append("<div class='thumb-wrapper' data-name='" + $(this).val() + "'><img class='loading' src='uploads/" +$(this).val()+"'><div class='thumbs-close' data-id='" + id + "'>x</div><input type='hidden' name='featured' value='No' id='hidden'></div>");
```

Here is the code for when I click on the thumb-wrapper class:

```
$( ".thumbs" ).on("click", ".thumb-wrapper", function(e) {
        var hidden = $(this).closest("#hidden").val("Yes");
        alert(hidden);
```

This currently alerts "undefined".

An example of the generated HTML is:

```
<div class="thumbs">
 <div class="thumb-wrapper" data-name="chocolate.jpg">
 <img class="loading" src="uploads/chocolate.jpg"><div class="thumbs-close" data-id="image_8">x</div>
 <input type="hidden" name="featured" value="No" id="hidden">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: @PhaniKumarM, I have updated the original question.

Comment: Where does the first JS code implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is `closest` is searching through up. You need to use `find` instead to search down instead of up.

```
var hidden = $(this).find("#hidden").val("Yes");
```

Jquery closest official explanation:

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing **up** through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

There were other related questions asking for an alternative to closest changing direction of search from up to down: [Is there an equivalent to .closest() that searches down the DOM tree instead of up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139375/is-there-an-equivalent-to-closest-that-searches-down-the-dom-tree-instead-of)

If you want to save the value on a var use:

```
var hiddenObj = $(this).find("#hidden");
var valueVar = hiddenObj.val();
alert(valueVar);
```

Comment: Thank you. the alert gives me [Object Object]. If I leave out yes and just have .val() then it alerts the current value i.e.: "No"

Comment: No, it gives me [Object Object] instead of "Yes".

Comment: Hmm. But the value of the hidden field does change. Just the alert says Object Object.

Comment: @user8463989  use `console.log()`  instead of alert to see what is inside objects! in chrome console

Comment: hidden is the object. Everything is ok. If you want to see the value put `alert($(this).find("#hidden").val("Yes"))`

Comment: If you want to save it on a var put this `othervar = $(this).find("#hidden").val()` and then `alert(othervar)`. I edited my answer with this.

Comment: Thank you. How do I change the value later? If I just get the current value `var hidden = $(this).find(".hidden").val();` and later want to change it after doing something? I tried `$(hidden).val("Yes");` but that does nothing

Comment: Sorry, I will ask a new related question

Answer (score 1):

You better change the input hidden to class:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="featured" value="No" class="hidden">


$( ".thumbs" ).on("click", ".thumb-wrapper", function(e) {
    var hidden = $(this).find(".hidden").val("Yes");
    alert(hidden);
```

you can not have multiple elements sharing the same id!